# Prove "If, in a country, there are $x$ fallow acres for every planted acre, yield per planted acre is $1+x$ times the yield per total acre."

Tags: proof-explanation

> If, in a country, there are $x$ fallow acres for every planted acre,
>   yield per planted acre is $1+x$ times the yield per total acre.
>
> Thus the ratio of yields per planted acre between the Soviet Union (S)
>   and the U.S. (U), $.68$,  is $1+x_S\over1+x_U$ times the ratio of
>   yields per total acre, $1.14$. Therefore ${1+x_S\over1+x_U}< 1$,
>   whence $x_S<x_U$. This means that in the U.S., there are more fallow
>   acres per planted acre than there are in the Soviet Union, so the
>   percentage of arable land left fallow is higher in the U. S.

Was the explanation for the question

> A ten year comparison between the United States and the Soviet Union
>   in terms of crop yields per acre revealed that when only planted
>   acreage is compared, Soviet yields were equal to 68 percent of United
>   States yields. When total agricultural acreage (planted acreage plus
>   fallow acreage) is compared, however, Soviet yield was 114 percent of
>   US yield. From the information above, show that a higher percentage of
>   total agricultural acreage was fallow in United States than in the
>   Soviet Union.

How do you prove

"If, in a country, there are $x$ fallow acres for every planted acre, yield per planted acre is $1+x$ times the yield per total acre."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through this one step at a time:

Say there are $n$ planted acres. For every planted acre, there are $x$ fallow acres, so there are $nx$ fallow acres. The number of total acres is therefore $nx + n$, or $(x+1)n$.

Now let $y$ be the total yield. To get the yield per something, we need to divide by that something. So the yield per planted acre is $\frac{y}{n}$, and the yield per total acre is $\frac{y}{(x+1)n}$.

Now $1+x$ times the yield per total acre $\frac{y}{(x+1)n}$ is equal to $\frac{(x+1)y}{(x+1)n}$, or $\frac{y}{n}$. This is equal to the yield per planted acre, thus the statement is proven.

Comment: What is the interpretation of $1+x$? What does that represent? Ratio of land mass?

Comment: @Germania As shown above, $(x+1)n$ is the total # of acres and $n$ is the # of planted acres. Thus, $x + 1 = \frac{(x+1)n}{n}$ is the ratio of the total # of acres to the # of planted acres. This is essentially what you're asking to prove.